# Non-nullable instance field '_selectedDate' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, widget, material-design

I am developing an Expenses Management App in flutter, Here I am trying to create a DateTimePicker using showDatePicker(). therefore Inside my presentDateTimePicker() function i am calling showDatePicker() method.

and I am creating a variable for selectedDate where I am not initializing it to a current value since it will change based on the user input.

Inside my `setState()` method I use `_selectedDate = pickedDate`.

Still, it shows an error saying "non-nullable instance field"

My widget

```
//flutter imports
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addTx;

  NewTransaction(this.addTx);

  @override
  _NewTransactionState createState() => _NewTransactionState();
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _amountController = TextEditingController();
  final _brandNameControlller = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  void _submitData() {
    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = double.parse(_amountController.text);
    final enteredBrandName = _brandNameControlller.text;

    if (enteredTitle.isEmpty || enteredAmount <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    widget.addTx(
      enteredTitle,
      enteredAmount,
      enteredBrandName,
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _presentDateTimePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2019),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    ).then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              autocorrect: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
              controller: _titleController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData,
              //onChanged: (val) {
              //titleInput = val;
              //},
            ),
            TextField(
              autocorrect: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
              controller: _amountController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData,
              //onChanged: (val) => amountInput = val,
            ),
            TextField(
              autocorrect: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Brand Name'),
              controller: _brandNameControlller,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData,
              //onChanged: (val) => brandInput = val,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 70,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(_selectedDate == null
                      ? 'No Date Chosen'
                      : 'Picked Date: ${DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate)}'),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: _presentDateTimePicker,
                    child: Text(
                      'Chose Date',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _submitData,
              child: Text('Add Transaction'),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              textColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button!.color,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value is nullable just mark the variable as such `DateTime? _selectedDate;`

And whenever you would use it just check for null first:

```dart
Text(_selectedDate == null
? 'No Date Chosen'
: 'Picked Date: ${DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!)}'),
// Here you do know that the value can't be null so you assert to the compiler that
```

Check out the [official docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#:%7E:text=If%20you%20run%20this%20Dart,has%20no%20%E2%80%9Clength%E2%80%9D%20getter.) on null safety they are extremely high quality and instructive.
There you can read about when to use nullable `?` non nullable or `late` variables.

Comment: Thank you so much. Pretty much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around in this situation

initialize the date with

```
DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.parse('0000-00-00');
```

and later on in text widget
instead of

```
Text(_selectedDate == null
? 'No Date Chosen'
: 'Picked Date: ${DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!)}'),
```

use

```
Text(_selectedDate == DateTime.parse('0000-00-00')
? 'No Date Chosen'
: 'Picked Date: ${DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!)}'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will change the value in the setState method, you can initialize the variable with

```
DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
```

and format it to the format you show the user, this would get rid of the error and if you are going to change it each time the user selects a date, seeing the current date as a starting value gives the user a starting point as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

**step1 :**  Put a  question mark **'?'** after DateTime data type such as **DateTime? _selectedDate;**

Adding a question mark indicates to Dart that the variable can be null. I expect that initially the _selectedDate is not set, so Dart is giving an error warning due to null-safety. By putting a question mark in the type, you are saying you expect that the variable can be null (which is why it fixes the error).

**step2 :** whenever you would use it just check for null first by adding a null check **(!)**

**After fixing errors your code is now :**

```
    //flutter imports
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addTx;

  NewTransaction(this.addTx);

  @override
  _NewTransactionState createState() => _NewTransactionState();
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _amountController = TextEditingController();
  final _brandNameControlller = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? _selectedDate;

  void _submitData() {
    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = double.parse(_amountController.text);
    final enteredBrandName = _brandNameControlller.text;

    if (enteredTitle.isEmpty || enteredAmount <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    widget.addTx(
      enteredTitle,
      enteredAmount,
      enteredBrandName,
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _presentDateTimePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2019),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    ).then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
             elevation: 5,
             child: Container(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
               child: Column(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   TextField(
                     autocorrect: true,
                     decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                     controller: _titleController,
                     onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData,
                     //onChanged: (val) {
                     //titleInput = val;
                     //},
                   ),
                   TextField(
                     autocorrect: true,
                     decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
                     controller: _amountController,
                     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                     onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData,
                     //onChanged: (val) => amountInput = val,
                   ),
                   TextField(
                     autocorrect: true,
                     decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Brand Name'),
                     controller: _brandNameControlller,
                     onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData,
                     //onChanged: (val) => brandInput = val,
                   ),
                   Container(
                     height: 70,
                     child: Row(
                       children: <Widget>[
                         Text(_selectedDate == null
                              ? 'No Date Chosen'
                              : 'Picked Date: ${DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!)}'),
                         FlatButton(
                           onPressed: _presentDateTimePicker,
                           child: Text(
                             'Chose Date',
                             style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                           ),
                           textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                   RaisedButton(
                     onPressed: _submitData,
                     child: Text('Add Transaction'),
                     color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                     textColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button!.color,
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           );
  }
}
```